# How can I capture a LongPressGesture action in WKInterfaceTable on a AppleWatch

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a table in with some dynamic rows. How can I capture a LongPressGesture when I long press on an item in the row. 
I Dragged a LongPressGestureRecognizer into a Table element and created a custom class for the row with a Handler for the gesture recognizer. But it doesn't capture the long press. Instead the

```
override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {
```

is triggered in the parent class with the table instance. Why isn't the longPress recognized?